# Load data from database on table using select2 in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I am trying to fetch data from database on a table in my application. The code works fine using input box but I can't get it to work with select box. Note that I used select2 to filter data in the selectbox.

Here is the Route:

```
 Route::get('get-student-info/', [ResultController::class, 'get_student_info'])->name('get_student_info');
```

Controller code:

```
public function get_student_info(Request $request)
{
    $search_name=$request['search'] ?? "";
    if ($search_name !=""){

            $data=User::where('admission_num','like','%'.$search_name.'%')->get();

            $output='';
        if(count($data)>0){

             $output ='
             <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">First Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Class</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';

            foreach($data as $row){
                $output .='
                <tr>
                <th scope="row">'.$row->name.'</th>
                <td>'.$row->lastname.'</td>
                <td>'.$row->class.'</td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }



     $output .= '
                 </tbody>
                </table>';



        }
        else{

            $output .='No results';

        }

        return $output;

        }

      }
```

Blade.php:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                                        
                                        <select class="form-select form-select-sm" name="search" id="search" aria-label="Default select example">
                                            <option></option>
                                                @foreach($admission as $admissions)
                                            <option value="{{ $admissions->admission_num }}">{{ $admissions->admission_num }}</option>
                                                @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="search_list"></div>
                                    <br><br>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3"></div>


                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                             $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
                                 var query= $(this).val();
                                 $.ajax({
                                    url:"get-student-info",
                                    type:"GET",
                                    data:{'search':query},
                                    success:function(data){
                                        $('#search_list').html(data);
                                    }
                             });
                             //end of ajax call
                            });
                            });
                        </script>
```

**NOTE:** The above code works perfectly when I used:

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter search name" class="form-control" onfocus="this.value=''">
```

But I cannot get it to work with selectbox.

Comment: I don't think `.on('keyup')` would work with a `<select>` element. `.on('change')` should, or `select2` has its own callback events: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events.

Comment: Sounds good! In the future, please attempt to do some debugging on your end. A simple `console.log()` inside of your `.on('keyup', function() { ... });` would have immediately told you if your code was working. Also, please don't just say "It's not working"; please fully explain what is not working, including any error messages, etc. The more details you provide the more likely it is you'll actually get any assistance.

Comment: You're quite welcome  If you still need assistance after trying with `change` (or something else), feel free to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72805640/edit) with more details, and we'll assist if we can. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much, @Tim Lewis, I got it solved following your suggestion. You have saved me a lot of headaches.

Comment: Excellent to hear! If you'd like, you're welcome to post your functioning code as an answer below; it might help someone else out in the future. Glad you got it working! 

Comment: Will do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved by adjusting the Ajax code. I used `on('select2:select')` event instead of the `.on(keyup)`. And also adjusted  `url:"get-student-info",` Below is the Ajax code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                                 $('#search').on('select2:select',function(){
                                     var query= $(this).val();
                                     console.log(query);

                                     $.ajax({
                                        url:'/get-student-info',
                                        type:"GET",
                                        data:{'search':query},
                                        success:function(data){
                                            $('#search_list').html(data);
                                            //console.log(data);
                                        }
                                 });
                                 //end of ajax call
                                });
                                });
```

Other parts of the code remain the same.